# Saving the CurrentPageIndex of Radgrids

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

so I'm currently using RadGrid to display the results of a link query. Each of these results has a bound item command that allows the user to go in and Edit or Delete that record. The problem arises when I'm paging through the grid and I edit a result on the 4th page. When I hit save, I want it to go back to the 4th page of the results but it always goes back to page one.

I'm currently using a query string to store the CurrentPageIndex when it jumps to the edit page and I pass it back after I save the record, but I'm having trouble ignoring the query string when I try to page normally since the NeedDataSource function is called every time I page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Save your RadGrid's current page index in `session` and use it .

Add this code in your edit function to save current Page index  !

```
Session["CurrentPageIndex"] = RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex;
```

Reuse your session value in

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       int PreviousPageIndex = 0;

       if (Session["CurrentPageIndex"] != null)
       {
           int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Session["CurrentPageIndex"]), out PreviousPageIndex );
       }

       RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = PreviousPageIndex ;
   }

 }
```